# Foundations of analysis - Natural number addition operator proof/definition

Tags: analysis, foundations, natural-numbers

In Landau's "Grundlagen der Analysis" the author states the following proposition which at the same time is a definition.

$$\text{Proposition 4/at the same time Definition 1. There is precisely one way to define an operation}$$

$$+: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, (x, y) \mapsto +(x, y) := x + y :=  (x + 1 = x' \quad \land \quad x + y' = (x + y)'.
$$

Where $'$ is the successor function of a natural number.

In Tao's Analysis I, the author just takes the operation of addition as a definition without proving existence and uniqueness (with the difference that Tao uses $0$ as the smallest natural number and Landau uses $1$).

Since when do we have to prove definitions? Proving a definition is new to me.

Comment: IMO, it is simply "too short" the exposition. We have a **Theorem** : "We have a function that to every pair of numbers $x, y$, assign in exactly one way a natural number such that 1) $f(x,1)=x++$ and 2) $f(x,y++) = f(x,y)++$.  Having proved that the function is "well defined" (i.e. there is a unique value for every "input" pair $x,y$) we may define a new symbol ("name") for it : $(x+y)$.

Comment: Yes, the well-defined part would be the uniqueness part of it. But why do we have to prove existence and don't just take it as a definition?

Comment: The Part A) of the Th shows that the "mapping" is a *function*, i.e. that for every $x$ there is at most one value of $f(x,y)$, for every $y$.

Comment: Part B) proves (by Induction) that the function is defined for every number, i.e. that the set $\mathfrak M$ of all $x$ for which it is defined (in exactly one way, by A)) the value $f(x,y)$, for every $y$, contains all the numbers, i.e. it is $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Compare with a standard set-theoretic development; see [*Axiomatic Set Theory*, by Patrick Suppes](https://books.google.it/books?id=sxr4LrgJGeAC&pg=PA142) page 142-144 : we have a general Theorem regarding the definitions by recursion and then we have the specific Defintion of $+$. Landau has "zipped" the two steps into one. (Landau's textbook is well-know for being "terse"...).

Comment: I understand the proof in Landau. But I do not understand why we have to prove that such an operation exists instead of just simply taking it as a definition. Tao in his Analysis I does precisely this. He states the addition and multiplication operations and then proceeds with proving the algebra laws. Only starting with the integers he begins proving that the operations are well-define. For example I've never seen a proof of the existence of the differentiation operator and so on. Thank you for the Suppes' book. I actually have that at home but haven't gone through it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when making a mathematical definition, there is some choice. You have mentioned one such situation: open one book, and the natural numbers include zero. Open another book, and zero is not an element of the natural numbers.
In Landau's booklet, the theorem you mention shows that there is no choice for the definition of natural-number addition $x+y$, if we insist on two rather mild requirements. (Requirements to which no one will object, given the intuitive notion "successor" and our experience of ordinary, primitive counting.)
Landau might have written the definition explicitly, but if he had done so, it would read something like the following.

> We define $+:N \times N \to N$ in the only way that it can be defined, in accordance with the previous theorem.

In summary, Landau is not "proving a definition". As always, definitions are arbitrary and subject to the court of popularity.

**Remark 1:** In proving the Commutative Law of Addition a few pages later, Landau calls upon the *proof of* Proposition 4. The proof is part of the greater development.

**Remark 2:** In the prefaces, Landau discusses Proposition 4 in relation to the Peano axioms, and relates his story of how it came to be included in his development.